# Dynamic array in C cause segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I have defined a dynamic array this way:

```
double   *n_data ;
int n_data_c = 0, n_cnt = 0;
n_data_c = count_lines_of_file("abnorm");
n_data = (double *)malloc(n_data_c * sizeof(double));
```

in a loop I calculate distance and do so:

```
n_cnt++;
n_data[n_cnt] = distance;
```

but it returns `segmentation fault` here : `n_data[n_cnt] = distance;`

I want to know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: In C you [should not cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/440558).

Comment: your source has many errors.

Answer (score 3):

Check what malloc returned, if it returned 0, then it failed.  More likely, I think, is your n_cnt is out of bounds.  If it's negative, or greater than or equal to n_data_c, then you'll get a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

You are overrunning your array buffer.. 
Compare n_cnt with n_data_c and only access the array if n_cnt < n_data_c/

```
n_cnt++;
if (n_cnt < n_data_c)
{
n_data[n_cnt] = distance;
}
```

Comment: `n_data_c` is 7 as my file has 7 lines and `n_cnt` is 1 at first iteration and then it returns segfault.

Answer (score 0):

`n_data_c = count_lines_of_file("abnorm");`

this is generating the segmentation fault. Check the value of `n_data_c`

Comment: @G one: I checked it, it returns 7 as my file has 7 lines.

Comment: `int n_data_c = 7, n_cnt = 0;
    n_data = (double *)malloc(n_data_c * sizeof(double));
    n_cnt++;
    n_data[n_cnt] = 10;` I tried this and its not giving me any seg fault
    printf("%f", n_data[n_cnt]);

Comment: Did you check passing of parameters into the `calculatedistance()` are they correct??

Answer (score 0):

Just try printing the value of n_data_c before mallocing.

Comment: I checked it, it returns 7 as my file has 7 lines.